# how to retrieve radio button value from database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
 If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
                Dim row As DataGridViewRow
                row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

 RadioButton1.Checked = row.Cells("gender").Value.ToString()
                RadioButton2.Checked = row.Cells("gender").Value.ToString()
```

I get the error conversion from string to type Boolean is not valid.

Comment: The error means what it says.  `Checked` is a boolean so `.ToString()` on anything wont fit

Comment: @Plutonix how to fix that ?

Comment: evaluate `row.Cells("gender").Value` in an expression and assign the result.  Please read[ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: This is VB so wouldn't the string "True" be implicitly converted to a boolean? I wonder if there is a spelling error. Plutonix is right though.

Comment: If gender is bit then implicit conversion would work. I thought the string representation would too. I am going to test it. Could you show the values in gender column along with data type?